Ubuntu 22.04 desktop encryption on raid 6 array and boot drive
During the ubuntu 22.04 desktop installation my goal is to have two ssd drives contain the root and boot and an encrypted raid 6 array (this is a fresh installation the raid 6 doesn't exist) I'm not seeing where or when to encrypt only the raid 6.
TIA for any advice.

Does the "encrypted Raid 6 array" exist? Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

You cannot build a RAID 6 with fewer than three drives, last but not least because RAID 6 is supposed to protect you from losing up to two drives.
In addition, RAID 6 will expand any write request to its internal block size. You can, in principle, reduce the RAID block size to a value that is sensible for your SSD (usually 512 bytes or 4 kB), but it does still create some overhead for random access.
In general, the order of operations is

set up regular partition table
mark partitions to be used for RAID as "use as physical volume for MD"
set up MD
partition the MD device

Bad ideas:

building a GPT partition table with no ESP
building LVM that uses both unencrypted and encrypted areas as physical volumes

Bootable RAID systems with software RAID are a bit of a tricky thing to get right.

I guess I mis-spoke.  The 2 SSD drives would just contain root & boot (not encrypted). My raid 6 has 8 drives ( needs to be encrypted) Thanks for the other tips.

Yes, then the only information you need is "every time you configure a layer, the new media will show up in the partitioner" -- so you set up the MD with the RAID 6 through the "set up MD" step, which gives you a large unpartitioned device, which you can then use as a LUKS volume, which gives you another large unpartitioned device which you can set up to contain your data (most sensible: use as an LVM PV).
